# Joining 3 lines to the line that matches a pattern

Tags: bash, perl, vim, awk, sed

I have a file in VI Editor like this:

```
I1 a b c d e f 
g h i j k l m     
o p q r s t u v     
w x y z     
I2 a b c d     
e f g h i j k l m     
n o p q r s t     
u v w x y z    
I3 a  b c d e     
f g h i j k l m n     
o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

I'm trying to merge the 3 line that are after the line starting with I(^I) like this:

```
I1 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z     
I2 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z    
I3 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

I have googled to see if I can join the 3 lines after the line containing `I1` (that is, the line beginning with `I` `[^I]`) in VI editor and found the Join command that joins the next line to the current line like `:g/^I/norm Jx`. But I would like to use this command for joining the next 3 lines to the current line.

It would be highly appreciated if any one can suggest me a method to do this via VI Editor or any scripting language.

Comment: Is the 3 lines a hard number? You want to join 3 lines but your example joins 4, 4, and 3 lines.

Comment: In VI (or better yet VIM): Go to the top line, press shift + J. Done.

Comment: Hi: My mistake in the last sample. It should have been 4 lines. Thank for the reminder.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way you could do it using awk:

```
awk 'NR>1&&/^I[0-9]/{print ""}{printf "%s", $0}END{print ""}' file.txt
```

When the line number is greater than 1 and the line starts with "I" followed by a digit, use `print ""` to print a newline. Use `printf` to print the contents of every line. In the END block (thanks [fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1983854/fedorqui)), print a final newline.

Testing it out on your file:

```
$ awk 'NR>1&&/^I[0-9]/{print ""}{printf "%s", $0}END{print ""}' file.txt
I1 a b c d e fg h i j k l mo p q r s t u vw x y z
I2 a b c de f g h i j k l mn o p q r s tu v w x y z
I3 a b c d ef g h i j k l m no p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Comment: Note this misses a final end line. You can solve it by using `END {print ""}`.

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there:

```
:g/^I/norm 4J
```

- `:g` takes a regex and a command
- `:norm 4J` is an "ex" command that executes "normal mode" commands. i.e. what you'd type.

See [`:help :g`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/repeat.html#:g) and [`:help :norm`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:norm)

---

Based on Peter's comment: `:g/^I/.,+3join` or `:g/^I/j4`

Comment: Some explanation for VI novices such as myself would be appreciated :)

Comment: I think globally `:g` search for `/^I/` perform normal command `norm` and `4J` is a repeat command of shift+j (join lines).

Comment: This will fail on the last block of the given sample because it doesn't have enough lines.

Comment: Forget `:normal` and just use `:join`

Comment: I love the range but you don't need it in this case for `:join`. e.g `:g/^I/j4`

Comment: Ah, missed the version with {count} in the docs

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure every block has the same number of lines, say 4:

```
:g/^I/norm 4J
```

If you can't be sure about the number of lines to join the problem becomes slightly more complex:

```
:g/^I/norm O    " separates every block with a blank line
:g//vipJ        " join each block into it's own line         
:g/^$/d         " removes every blank line
```

If you don't mind thinking a little bit outside the box, this command will work with any block size:

```
:%join|s/ I/\rI/g    " join the whole buffer into one single line
                     " then substitute every ' I' with `\rI`
```

Comment: +1 I like the `:join`/`:s` approach myself. If you don't mind the last block not being joined you can do `:g/^I/,//-j` to join arbitrary  number of lines between blocks

Comment: For joining all the lines, it could be necessary to rotect against 'ignorecase': `%join|s/ \CI/\rI/g`

Answer (score 2):

```
tr -d "\n" <filename | sed 's/ \+/ /g;s/ I/\nI/g'
```

Output:

```
I1 a b c d e f g h i j k l m o p q r s t u v w x y z
I2 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
I3 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` makes it:

```
awk '/^I[0-9]/ {if (f) print f; f=""} {f=sprintf("%s%s", (f?f FS:""), $0)} END {print f}' file
```

It keeps adding the lines into a variable `f`. When a line starting with `I` + digit is found, it prints it.

for the given input returns:

```
I1 a b c d e f g h i j k l m o p q r s t u v w x y z
I2 a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
I3 a  b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Comment: Thanks fedorqui. This worked too. I have both the methods. Thanks for the immediate reply and help.

Answer (score 1):

Perlish answer;

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) {
   chomp;
   s/\s+/ /g;
   if ( m/^I/ ) { print "\n" };
   print;
}

__DATA__
I1 a b c d e f 
g h i j k l m     
o p q r s t u v     
w x y z     
I2 a b c d     
e f g h i j k l m     
n o p q r s t     
u v w x y z    
I3 a  b c d e     
f g h i j k l m n     
o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Comment: Thanks Sobrique. Built my script based on yours and some modifications.

Answer (score 1):

A solution in pure bash:

```
#! /bin/bash

start="I"
cur=
while read line ; do
    if test "${line:0:1}" = "$start" ; then
        test "$cur" = "" || { echo "$cur" ; cur= ;}
    fi
    cur+="$line"
done << EOT
I1 a b c d e f 
g h i j k l m     
o p q r s t u v     
w x y z     
I2 a b c d     
e f g h i j k l m     
n o p q r s t     
u v w x y z    
I3 a  b c d e     
f g h i j k l m n     
o p q r s t u v w x y z 
EOT

echo "$cur"
```

Answer (score 0):

On Vim, in addition to the ex commands pointed by glen and romainl, you could record a macro:

```
qm/^I<enter>vnJq
```

Then repeat it twice:

```
2@m
```

Explanation

- qm  -  start recording a macro on a given register (`m`on this case)
- /^I<kbd>enter</kbd>  - search for regex `^I`
- v - start visual selection
- n - select text before the next occurrence of the regex (this step and the previous could be replaced for `V3j` if the number of lines is fixed)
- J - join selected lines
- q - stop recording the macro